# Deleting mails from IMAP Server

Tags: c#, .net, imap, chilkat

How do i delete mails from IMAP Server. I am using chilkat

```
Chilkat.EmailBundle bundle = imapClient.FetchHeaders(mset);
```

There is a method in bundle but it does not delete the mail from Server.
Regards
Sanchaita

Answer (score 1):

There is good documentation (including code examples) on the Chilkat website:

[Delete Email Individually (One at a time) from an IMAP Mailbox](http://www.example-code.com/csharp/imap_deleteIndividualEmails.asp)

Also:

[Delete Email from an IMAP Mailbox](http://www.example-code.com/csharp/imap-delete-email.asp)

Other IMAP examples:

[IMAP C# Examples](http://www.example-code.com/csharp/imap.asp)

Hope these help.

---

**Edit:**

As per the documentation on the page below:

[Chilkat C# EmailBundle Class Reference](http://www.chilkatsoft.com/refdoc/csEmailBundleRef.html)

Both the RemoveEmail and RemoveEmailByIndex methods only remove the emails from the bundle and not from the server. You will need to use another method as described in the links above to remove the message from the server.

---

**Edit**

I am not very familiar with the Chilkat library however from the documentation it seems like the "GetEmail" method in the EmailBundle class will retrieve a mail at a certain index and then you can use the "AppendMail" method in the IMap class to upload the mail to a particular inbox as specified in the following example:

[Upload (Append) Email to an IMAP Mailbox](http://www.example-code.com/csharp/imap_appendEmail.asp)

I hope this helps, if it does please mark it as answered.

Comment: The link given was extremely helpful. Now I am able to delete a mail at a certain index. Now how do i upload a mail at the same index.